# HashTable: Segmentation fault ao inserir - C

Tags: c, array, estrutura-de-dados

Estou a tentar implementar uma hashtable, em que a tabela seria um array de "baldes" em que cada um continha informação do utilizador, meu código:

```
#define tam_inicial 23

typedef struct user{
    char nick[6];
    char nome[26];
}user;

typedef struct hashtable{
    int tam;
    user **baldes;
}hashtable;

int tam = tam_inicial;

hashtable * create() {
    hashtable *htable = malloc(sizeof(htable));
    htable->tam = tam_inicial;
    htable->baldes = calloc(tam_inicial, sizeof(htable->baldes));

    return htable;
}

int hash(char *string) {
    int hashVal = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < strlen(string);i++){
        hashVal += (int)string[i];
    }

    return hashVal % tam;
}

bool isPrime(int num){
    if(num==2){
        return true;
    }
    if(num % 2==0){
        return false;
    }
    for(int i=3; i*i<num; i+=2){
        if(num%i==0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int Prime_num(int old_size){
    for(int i = old_size; i < old_size * 2 +10; i++){
        if(isPrime(i) && i >= 2*old_size){
            return i;
        }
    }
}

hashtable *resize_HashTable(hashtable *HashTable){
    if(load_factor()){
        int tmp = Prime_num(tam);
        HashTable = realloc(HashTable, tmp * sizeof(user));
        tam = tmp;
    }
    return HashTable;
}

void inserir(hashtable *HashTable, char *nome, char *nick){
    HashTable = resize_HashTable(HashTable);
    int hash_value = hash(nick);
    while(HashTable->baldes[hash_value] != 0 && hash_value < HashTable->tam){
        hash_value++;
    }
    strcpy(HashTable->baldes[hash_value]->nome, name);
    strcpy(HashTable->baldes[hash_value]->nick, nick);
    HashTable->tam = HashTable->tam++;
}
```

Por alguma razão estas 2 linhas dão erro de "segmentation fault":

```
strcpy(HashTable->baldes[hash_value]->nome, name);
strcpy(HashTable->baldes[hash_value]->nick, nick);
```

É como se não conseguisse aceder às variaveis "nome" e "nick" da struct user para por lá os nomes/nicks

Alguma razão para isto acontecer? Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Como é o código das funções `resize_HashTable` e `hash`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa já coloquei lá na pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe esse trecho:

```
HashTable = resize_HashTable(HashTable);
int hash_value = hash(nick);
while(HashTable->baldes[hash_value] != 0 && hash_value < HashTable->tam){
    hash_value++;
}
```

Vamos supor que `HashTable->tam` seja 23 e que o `hash_value` retornado seja -1904468. O que vai acontecer? Segmentation fault porque você vai estar acessando `HashTable->baldes[hash_value]` fora do tamanho certo.

Acho que o que você tem que fazer é isso:

```
HashTable = resize_HashTable(HashTable);
int hash_value = hash(nick);
int balde = hash_value % HashTable->tam;
if (balde < 0) balde += HashTable->tam;
while (HashTable->baldes[balde] != 0 && balde < HashTable->tam) {
    balde++;
}
```

Mas isso daí só resolve uma parte do problema. Pois se esse `while` chegar ao final do array (especialmente se ele já tiver começado lá) e não encontrar um lugar livre para colocar o nome/nick, ele vai sair do limite do array e dar um segmentation fault ao invés de voltar ao começo. Assim sendo, você deve fazer isso:

```
HashTable = resize_HashTable(HashTable);
int hash_value = hash(nick);
int balde_inicial = hash_value % HashTable->tam;
if (balde_inicial < 0) balde_inicial += HashTable->tam;
int balde = balde_inicial;
while (HashTable->baldes[balde] != 0 && balde != balde_inicial - 1) {
    balde++;
    balde %= HashTable->tam;
}
```

Se o `HashTable` ficar cheio, isso será um laço infinito. Por isso, é importante que o `resize_HashTable` garanta que uma `HashTable` cheia nunca será retornada.

[EDITADO]: Ok, a pergunta foi editada e a sua função `hash` nunca retorna valores assim. No entanto, a sua função `hash` não deveria se basear no tamanho **inicial** da tabela `hash`. Se o tamanho da tabela mudar com o `resize_HashTable`, a função `hash` não muda junto. Além disso, você pode ter múltiplas tabelas em memória cada uma com um tamanho diferente.

Um outro problema é que se a string for suficientemente grande, a função `hash` dará um overflow e poderá retornar um valor negativo.

A solução é simplesmente tirar o `% tam` da função `hash`. Quem tem que se preocupar com isso para saber em qual balde o dado vai ser colocado é a tabela hash e não a função de `hash` que não sabe em qual tabela vai ser usada. A função `hash` só se preocupa em retornar um número arbitrário (possivelmente negativo) que represente a string.

Comment: eu já coloquei o resto do código na pergunta, apesar de essa parte que mencionou de facto poder dar erro, para os caso que eu testei o hash_value estava a ser 20 o que está dentro do limite do array, dai eu não perceber o erro

Comment: @MiguelD Acabei de editar a resposta de novo.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, só mais uma coisa, quanto à função de inicializar a tabela, devo usar malloc ou calloc? eu pensei em calloc pq queria inicializar a tabela a 0 para facilitar a identificação dos "baldes" livres

Comment: @MiguelD Acho que o `calloc` está ok. Dá para inicializar com `malloc`, mas aí você teria que limpar o conteúdo do bloco de memória alocado para usá-lo, e é isso exatamente o que o `calloc` faz.